# C# Dynamic List to Static List

Tags: c#, event-log

From the documentation of the Event Log Class the EventLogEntryCollection is a dynamic list of event log entries. It recommends that the Count property is used directly instead of storing its value in a variable. Implementing this behavior:

```
private void ReadEventLog()
{
    EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application", "TheGreatestMachineInTheWorld");
    EventLogEntryCollection eventLogEntries = eventLog.Entries;
    for (int i = 0; i < eventLogEntries.Count; i++){
        EventLogEntry entry = eventLog.Entries[i];
        //Do Some processing on the entry
}
```

Is slow for large event logs ( >20000 entries). The reason for the for loop instead of a foreach is because I need the iterator location to indicate how close this thing is to finishing.

Storing the count variable and iterating over that:

```
int eventLogEntryCount = eventLogEntries.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < eventLogEntryCount; i++){
        EventLogEntry entry = eventLog.Entries[i];
        //Do Some processing on the entry
}
```

Provides a noticeable performance boost. However it opens the possibility for an index out of range exception if the event log is being written to as the processing happens. Is there a way to store this list statically so the count does not change?

Comment: Is the `eventLog` object being written to or the machine event log being written to while the program is running?

Comment: That would be the machine event log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to store this list statically so the count does not change?

It sounds like you want something like:

```
List<EventLogEntry> entries = eventLogEntries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToList();
```

That will fetch *all* the log entries (at that time) into a `List<T>`, which will then be quick to access either with the indexer or with another `foreach`.

Of course, you may find it's slow just to *fetch* all the log entries - you should experiment with that.

Comment: I will try it and report back here after some thorough testing!

Comment: As expected, it's very slow to cast the event log entries to another list. I'll play around and see what I can do to speed it up.

Comment: @Dudemanword: No, the *casting* is not slow at all - it's *fetching* the entries that will be slow. You'd see the same issue if you *just* iterated through the original list and ignored everything.